# Booting directly from LiveUSB on a USB Stick with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, live-usb

I have created a bootable USB stick from the 12.04 build of Ubuntu and I'm finding it is better for my laptop than the Windows Vista that came on it.

However, I don't want to create a dual boot system at this time.

Is there a way to disable the "Try It" or "Install It" window when the system starts up so that it boots directly to the desktop from the USB stick?

Thank you in advance.

Colby

Comment: What you are looking for is a persistent USB install??: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use these ways on your flash drive to directly skip to Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu.

There are 3 ways:

**The easy way:** Download UNetBootin or PendriveLinux for Windows. Select your ISO, in this case, Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD since you want it to boot directly to Ubuntu and not the menus. Select the Ubuntu ISO you downloaded, and the directory of your flash drive. If you want to prevent deletion of files every time you boot, check the "Enable Persistence" box. Just press Next and that's it! Your 12.04 Ubuntu will boot up directly to LiveCD.

**The alternate easy way:** If your bootable stick already has persistence (preventing deletion of files every time you boot), then open up Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubiquity
```

This will remove Ubiquity, the LiveCD Installer. (Warning: You may not be able to Install Ubuntu using your USB after this.)

**The not-so-easy way:** Using YUMI or some other software, add a GRUB Bootloader to your USB stick and modify the boot menu to directly skip to LiveCD. I don't have any knowledge of this, you may want to consult other users.

But the first option is the best and does it's job without fuss. Happy exploring the world of Ubuntu :)